# Organization: Ways to link/group documents with emails?

Tags: email, file-management, documents

I like keeping my stuff organized, but short of printing everything out and keeping it in an actual file cabinet, I've never figured out a good way to link/group document files with related emails. This means that when I'm looking for something, I often have to search in my email program, and then through the documents stored in some filesystem folder.

Has anyone out there come up with a neat way to group related stuff like this for searching, archiving, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the email to the folder. Outlook allows drag and drop the email into a folder. I do it for all product serials. Install documentation, etc. What email client are you using?

Comment: Outlook/Windows at work, Firebird/Ubuntu at home. I tried doing that some years back, and it looked like it was going to work, but Outlook kept crashing. I'll give that another try.

Comment: OK this works fine with Outlook. I remember now that Outlook used to crash if it wasn't already open and you double-clicked on a mail item icon in Windows Explorer. This is probably what everyone else has been doing all this time; I just couldn't make it work and never thought to try again over the years...